# Testing Django Inline ModelForms: How to arrange POST data?

Tags: python, django, testing, inline

I have a Django 'add business' view which adds a new business with an inline 'business_contact' form.

The form works fine, but I'm wondering how to write up the unit test - specifically, the 'postdata' to send to self.client.post(settings.BUSINESS_ADD_URL, postdata)

I've inspected the fields in my browser and tried adding post data with corresponding names, but I still get a 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with' error when run.

Anyone know of any resources for figuring out how to post inline data?

Relevant models, views & forms below if it helps. Lotsa thanks.

MODEL:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    """ Contact details for the representatives of each business """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True, help_text=settings.SLUG_HELPER_TEXT)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table='business_contact'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.surname)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return('business_contact', (), {'contact_slug': self.slug })

class Business(models.Model):
    """ The business clients who you are selling products/services to """
    business = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, help_text=settings.SLUG_HELPER_TEXT)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    primary_contact = models.ForeignKey('Contact', null=True, blank=True, related_name='primary_contact')
    business_type = models.ForeignKey('BusinessType')
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'business'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.business

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '%s%s/' % (settings.BUSINESS_URL, self.slug)
```

VIEWS:

```
def business_add(request):
    template_name = 'business/business_add.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddBusinessForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            business = form.save(commit=False)
            contact_formset = AddBusinessFormSet(request.POST, instance=business)
            if contact_formset.is_valid():
                business.save()
                contact_formset.save()
                contact = Contact.objects.get(id=business.id)
                business.primary_contact = contact
                business.save()
                #return HttpResponse(help(contact))
                #business.primary = contact.id
                return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.BUSINESS_URL)
        else:
            contact_formset = AddBusinessFormSet(request.POST)
    else:
        form = AddBusinessForm()
        contact_formset = AddBusinessFormSet(instance=Business())
    return render_to_response(
            template_name,
            {
            'form': form,
            'contact_formset': contact_formset,
            },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
            )
```

FORMS:

```
class AddBusinessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        exclude = ['deleted','primary_contact',]

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        exclude = ['deleted',]


AddBusinessFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Business,
        Contact,
        can_delete=False,
        extra=1,
        form=AddBusinessForm,
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have not included the management form in your data.  You need to include `form-TOTAL_FORMS` (total number of forms in the formset, default is 2), `form-INITIAL_FORMS` (the initial number of forms in the formset, default is 0) and `form-MAX_NUM_FORMS` (the maximum number of forms in the formset, default is '').

See the [Formset documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#id2) for more information on the management form.